# How to remove p tags around img and iframe tags in the acf wysiwyg field

Tags: images, wysiwyg, wp-autop

I am querying an advanced custom fields wysiwyg field. Problem is in the output wordpress wraps occasional imgs and iframes with p tags no matter what i try. Deactivate the wpautop works `remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');`but if i try to exclude only imgs and iframes with the following snippet it fails:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to accomplish that goal? Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you want to strip the p tags for img's and iframe's for advanced custom fields you have to exchange `the_content` with `acf_the_content` . The code looks that way:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```